# TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand KeyObject

Tags: jwt, typeerror, tsconfig, angular16

```
When I try to log in to the system where I have defined the username and password, I get the error "TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand KeyObject". I edited angular.js and other contents, but I have not been able to fully solve the problem.
I am using the following versions:
```

> Angular CLI: 16.2.2 Node: 18.18.0
> Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
> OS: win32 x64`enter code here`
> Angular: 16.2.8
> ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
> ... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
> ... platform-server, router
> @angular-devkit/architect 0.1602.6
> @angular-devkit/build-angular 16.2.6
> @angular-devkit/core 16.2.2
> @angular-devkit/schematics 16.2.6
> @angular/cdk 16.2.7
> @angular/cli 16.2.2
> @angular/fire 7.6.1
> @angular/material 16.2.7
> @angular/material-moment-adapter 16.2
> @ngtools/webpack 16.2.6
> @nguniversal/builders 16.2.0
> @nguniversal/express-engine @schematics/angular 16.2.0
> rxjs  7.8.1
> typescript 5.1.6
> webpack 5.88.2
> zone.js 0.13.3

I can get a solution suggestion for " ERROR TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand KeyObject ".

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Provide a [mcve] of your code and the error.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will take it into consideration.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide the requested information as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to compatible package installations for Angular 16!
To solve my own problem, you should install "npm i browser-crypto" as an additional package compatible with version 8.5.1 of jsonwebtoken 9.0.2 software. Also, the content of the tsconfig.json file:
"browser": {"crypto": true,} and
"paths": {"crypto": ["node_modules/crypto-browserify"]
You should update it as .